# How to set current directory while working with an OLE Automation Server

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, ole

I am trying to simply create an OLE EXE server's instance through `CreateDispatch` call but apparently it fails because my Current directory is not correct. The error I get is "Server Initialization Failed". I debugged the `CreateDispatch` code and found out that it does three things.

1. CoCreateInstance  //In my case this succeeds
2. OleRun            //This fails in my case with error 'Server execution failed'
3. QueryInterface for IDispatch

I tried to launch the process through `CreateProcess` as well but it fails if I don't provide it a correct `CurrentDirectory` in its 8th Argument which clearly means that in my case `CurrentDirectory` is not correct and I have to provide it to get it working.

I know that parent's `CurrentDirectory` is passed on when a parent is trying to spawn a process. So, I tried changing parent's `CurrentDirectory` to appropriate directory via `SetCurrentDirectory` API call. This works in case of `CreateProcess` but doesn't work in case of `CreateDispatch` giving me the same error and failing on the same `OleRun` call inside.

Does anybody have any idea how I can pass on the CurrentDirectory to `CreateDispatch`? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have the currect directory set to your application directory, then you shoul djust do thi sin your "main" of your program. You can do this with `GetModuleFileName` and then use `splitpath` to get the directory and tehn call `SetCurrentDirectory`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain()
{
    TCHAR szDrive[_MAX_DRIVE];
    TCHAR szPath[_MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szName[_MAX_FNAME];
    TCHAR szExt[_MAX_EXT];
    TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szModName, MAX_PATH);
    _tsplitpath(szModName, szDrive, szPath, szName, szExt);

    TCHAR szAppDir[MAX_PATH];
    _tcscpy_s(szAppDir, szDrive);
    _tcscat_s(szAppDir, szPath);
    SetCurrentDirectory(szAppDir);
    _tprintf(szAppDir);
}
```